# Why can I not declare a temporary variable in a boolean expression in Java?

Tags: java, java-7

I was trying to implement something like Guava's [nullToEmpty](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.String)) without making two calls to a method.

My original call is:

```
return ((getElement(locator) != null) ? getElement(locator).getText() : StringUtils.EMPTY;
```

which I tried to shorten to:

```
return ((Element element = getElement(locator)) != null) ? element.getText() : StringUtils.EMPTY;
```

But I get `Element cannot be resolved to a variable`, `element cannot be resolved`, and `Syntax error on token "element", delete this token`.

This works:

```
Element element;
return ((element = getElement(locator)) != null) ? element.getText() : StringUtils.EMPTY;
```

What's wrong with declaring and assigning at the same time in an expression?

Comment: If you want to know "what's wrong" with it, ask James Gosling.  Some languages allow this kind of thing.  Java doesn't.  Probably because it makes things harder to read.

Comment: @ajb this is what prompted the question; I felt certain I had done this before in the C-family.

Answer (score 3):

Because that isn't a block, and you can't declare a variable in parenthesis unless it's a `for` loop. Also, your test should be `!= null` or calling `getText()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

```
Element element = getElement(locator);
return (element != null) ? element.getText() : StringUtils.EMPTY;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because `element` is already out of scope after you've resolved the conditional statement.

Comment: So this is one instance where a scope is defined by parens rather than braces?